# 2 retrofit calls 1 adapter

Tags: android, gridview, retrofit

I call API for popular Movies (I need poster and title) and popular TV Shows (poster and title). I need to do it with 2 different asynchronous calls, put data into `List<PopularMovieAdapterObject> podaci` and `setAdapter`. Adapter is for `GridView`, so basically I need a mix of popular movies and popular tv shows in one gridview. This is my code:

```
       PopularMoviesFromAPI popularMoviesFromAPI = new PopularMoviesFromAPI();

   popularMoviesFromAPI.getPopularMoviesInfo(new PopularMoviesFromAPI.GenericCallback() {
       @Override
       public void success(@NonNull List<String> posterURL, List<String> movieTVName) {
           List<PopularMovieAdapterObject> podaci = new ArrayList<>();
           for(int i=0; i<(posterURL.size()/2); i++){
               podaci.add(new PopularMovieAdapterObject("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + posterURL.get(i), movieTVName.get(i)));
           }

           PopularMoviesAdapter popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.popular_movies_item, podaci);

           popularMoviesGridView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void failure(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {

       }
   });

   popularMoviesFromAPI.getPopularTVShowsInfo(new PopularMoviesFromAPI.GenericCallback() {
       @Override
       public void success(@NonNull List<String> posterURL, List<String> movieTVName) {
           List<PopularMovieAdapterObject> podaci = new ArrayList<>();
           for(int i=0; i<(posterURL.size()/2); i++){
               podaci.add(new PopularMovieAdapterObject("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + posterURL.get(i), movieTVName.get(i)));
           }

           PopularMoviesAdapter popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.popular_movies_item, podaci);

           popularMoviesGridView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void failure(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {

       }
   });
```

Right now I can either put movies OR tv shows in `GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you are setting the adapter twice.

Try:

1. not passing the List (podaci) as an argument to your adapter class;
2. in the constructor of your adapter, set the list as an empty list initially;
3. create a method that sets the list of adapter by adding the podaci elements one by one at the end to the existing list.

Comment: or s/he can call synchronous call instead of asynchronous :)

Comment: Yes, that is also an option:)